Is Element Present Method Broke
I updated my framework and this method I have used for "is element present" broke and I am not sure why?? When the element is found, no issue and it returns true. When the element is not found, instead of returning false, it throws the below error and fails the test case.
Any ideas what I am missing here?

OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//my[@id='xpath']"}

Element locator
public const string eleVal = "//my[@id='xpath']";

public IWebElement _eleVal { get { return Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(eleVal )); } }

Method to get status. It fails on this when the element is not not found.
public bool GetValue()
{
    bool ele = Driver.IsElementPresent(_eleVal);

    if (ele)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

Method that has always worked
public static bool IsElementPresent(IWebElement element)
{
    bool result;

    try
    {
        result = element.Displayed;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    catch (WebDriverException)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return result;
}


The problem is that inside GetValue() _eleVal gets evaluated which is where the .FindElement() call is that fails. That's outside of your try-catch. If you want your try-catch to actually catch that exception you need to use .FindElement() inside there. I would write this all a different way.

Instead of storing a locator as just the string component of an XPath, store it as a By locator. That enables you to change the locator type and locator string all in one place. It also allows you to pass that By around to methods, etc.
string eleVal = "//my[@id='xpath']";

becomes
By elementLocator = By.XPath("//my[@id='xpath']");


This looks like it might be a portion of a page object? Core to the page object design is to hide the details of the page from the user and just present them with a nice, clean API to call for a given page. That means that locators should be private.
public const string eleVal = "//my[@id='xpath']";

becomes
private readonly By elementLocator = By.XPath("//my[@id='xpath']");


Don't store state in your page objects (or whatever class your element locator is in). This can easily lead to StaleElementExceptions and other issues. It can also prevent you from running your tests in parallel, etc. Storing state in this case is storing a IWebElement in a class field. Instead just store the locator and when you need to find the element, use .FindElement() or a WebDriverWait. Remove the line below
public IWebElement _eleVal { get { return Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(eleVal )); } }

and just pass in the locator from #1 into a method to find that element, etc.

GetValue() can be simplified significantly. It also should take in a By locator parameter. The whole method can be reduced to
public bool GetValue(By locator)
{
    return Driver.IsElementPresent(locator);
}

Having said that, I don't know why GetValue() exists. It doesn't "get a value" like the name implies. It also doesn't do anything itself... IsElementPresent() does all the work so I would remove GetValue() unless there's additional code you haven't included.

Combining several of the previous recommendations, I would rewrite IsElementPresent() to take in a By locator instead of an IWebElement. That will allow you to grab the element at the moment it's needed avoiding many times issues like StaleElementExceptions, etc.

Your method, IsElementPresent(), is checking to see if the element is visible, not present. Present means the element is in the DOM, not that it's visible or clickable. .Displayed checks to see if the element is visible and that's what you are returning. I would rename this method to IsElementVisible(). I also wrote an IsElementPresent() method in case you wanted it.


Taking all of this into account, here's how I would rewrite all this.

Locators are private, readonly, and are Bys.
GetValue() is no longer needed. If you need the equivalent of GetValue() call IsElementVisible(locator).
Simplify and rename IsElementPresent() to IsElementVisible(locator) to match what it does and take in a By locator.
Write IsElementPresent(locator) to match what the method name states and take a By locator.

The full updated code
private readonly By elementLocator = By.XPath("//my[@id='xpath']");

...

public bool IsElementPresent(By locator)
{
    return Driver.FindElements(locator).Any();
}

public bool IsElementVisible(By locator)
{
    var e = Driver.FindElements(locator);
    if (e.Count == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        return e.ElementAt(0).Displayed;
    }
    catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}


Thanks Jeff.  This was a framework using PageFactory that was all deprecated so that was all removed. Everything was working but this method went a bit south. Yes this is using POM.

yeah it is helpful but I was not looking to rewrite the framework but just to resolve the method that broke. I have methods for what you have posted already for all locators but in this instance, I am trying to use the IsElementPresent method using the iwebelements. There are over 100 calls to this method that are breaking when false.

I explained the issue in my first few sentences.
